# Instruments does not show me the real reference count

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, instruments

I am attempting to debug an issue where an object is released too many times and is then deallocated by the event loop. The next time I try to read from the object, the application crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

To debug, I am enabling NSZombies and then using the Zombies profile with Instruments. I then reach the point where my app crashes and Instruments informs me about a message being sent to a deallocated instance. So far, so good.

It does a very good job of showing me where libraries such as UIKit are releasing and retaining the pointer to my object, but it does not show me where my own code is doing this. It is also not displaying the true reference count. By the time that Instruments says that the reference count is 1, the reference count is actually 8 according to printing out the reference count in gdb.

I have investigated the possibility that Instruments is somehow filtering the output but it would appear that I really am recording every release and retain event. It absolutely must be something in my application because my view controller is instantly deallocated after displaying, meaning that attempting to do anything that would send a message to the controller would crash it.

After placing a breakpoint in the dealloc method, I found that my object is indeed being deallocated by the event loop, so this is not a case of a rogue call to dealloc by something else.

Comment: Post the code where you are instantiating the ViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't rely on reference count as Apple's Framework classes may hold their own references to your objects. The reference count is meaningless for debugging.

Comment: Indeed. I have seen pretty high refcounts on objects that should only have one or two, as far as I could see. But behind the scenes, you get a lot more of them, especially when instrumenting. But even without Instruments, the count is often much higher (but never lower) than you think it should be.

Comment: Surely the two numbers should match up though? Does Instruments not see the releases and retains internally within Apple's frameworks? And do you know why Instruments isn't logging the calls that my software makes to release and retain?

Comment: I solved this a few hours later but forgot to update - It turns out that in actual fact I had set my file's owner to be my custom ViewController as well as setting a TableViewController within the nib to be the same ViewController, hence my confusion. This ended up creating two instances of the same ViewController; one of which was quickly eaten up the next time the event loop ran. All the actions in the UI however were attached to this now deallocated instance, hence the crash. Thank you for your time in reading and responding to my question and enjoy some delicious reputation on me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click in the (i) left of the Allocations-Graph
2. Set "Record reference counts"
3. You are done ;)

[image: Activate reference count]